# UIButton tap should be recognized simultaneously with other gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIButton` in a `UIView` that contains `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

The problem is that if I hover the UIButton it steals the touch events and the pan gesture never fires.

What I want is the tap gesture recognizer on `UIButton` to be recognized simultaneously with the pan gesture of it's superview.

Ideas?

I've tried enumerating the `UIButton` `gestureRecognizers` property and setting each gesture recognizer the delegate to `self` and then using the `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` delegate method returning `YES` but it didn't worked out.

Comment: so you want a callback from pangesture and tapgesture simultaneously ?

Comment: have you checked if the delegate is set properly by gesture's object.

Comment: also , mind sharing some code ?